# Как подключить javascript в qt?

Tags: qt

Всем привет. Пытаюсь подключить скрипты в Qt, для этого в файле .pro добавляю QT += script и в .h подключаю #include <QtScript/QScriptEngine>, но он не находит соответствующие модули. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно подключить скрипты в qt? Пытался гуглить, но таким способом как описываются на сайтах у меня не получается, он не узнает модули, в чем может быть проблема? Проект создавался как Qt Widjets

Comment: Модуль QtScript deprecated уже достаточно давно. Возьмите практически полностью аналогичный ему `QJSEngine `

Comment: А проблема скорее всего в том, что модуль не установлен, его нужно отдельно из Maintenance Tool установить

Comment: Спасибо большое. У меня Qt 5.15 , оказывается в .pro файле нужно было подключить не QT += script, а QT += quick и в файле .h подключить QJSEngine